# Stacked progress bars with `progress` module in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, terminal, progress-bar, command-line-interface

I am running [`progress`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress) v2.0.3 with NodeJS v10.9.0 on MacOS 10.10.5 and try to implement stacked progress bars like this:

```
'use strict';
const ProgressBar = require('progress');


const foo = new ProgressBar('Processing [:bar] :percent :etas', { total: 100 });
let timerFoo = setInterval( () => {
  foo.tick();
  if (foo.complete) {
    clearInterval(timerFoo);
  }
}, 10);


const bar = new ProgressBar('Processing [:bar] :percent :etas', { total: 100 });
let timerBar = setInterval( () => {
  bar.tick();
  if (bar.complete) {
    clearInterval(timerBar);
  }
}, 200);
```

Despite of having a stacked output of both of the defined progress bars after completion of the first one (or at the end when both are running at the same timer interval), I am not able to get this for uncompleted progress bars. How can I implement stacked progress bars (need four bars in total) with the [`progress`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress) module?

Comment: u want the second bar(or even if there are more) to remain uncompleted after the first is completed?

Comment: I want independent progress bars which are stacked. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53986243/3991125) for a dedicated module extending the basic `progress` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dedicated module called [`multi-progress`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multi-progress) which extends the [`progress`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress) module's API to allow multiple progress bars:

> This module adds a layer on top of the API of [progress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress) that allows for
>   multiple progress bars.

Comment: In case you want to simultaneously show multiple progress bars and also system log from `console.log` output, you can use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-with-statusbar